# Popupbox with check box and confirm in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, .net

How will show the message and a check box to confirm if the user wants to submit.

Comment: what you have made so far

Comment: I want have a popupbox with check box confirmation.if user check then user click confirm otherwise close.

Comment: As said @Evonet you have to use modal, because add checkbox on popupbox is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery.  If you're using a front end library like Bootstrap then consider their Modal component:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I want user confirmation by popbox.on button click

Comment: When the user fills in all the fields and hits submit, the logic will check if there is already an entry on the same day with the same details in the database.

Comment: If yes, we will show the message and a check box to confirm if the user wants to submit even if it’s a duplicate.

Comment: Would be a much better answer if you had code. This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Are you sure?</h1>
    
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('sendNew').disabled = !this.checked;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sendNew" class="inputButton" id="sendNew" value=" Send "  disabled="true"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox?